# How to create a snapshot of ERC-20 token balances?

Tags: erc-20

Token holder snapshots are useful for airdrops, dividends and such. How to create one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The instructions below are for senior software developers, who know Docker and UNIX command line. You will also need an [Ethereum API node](https://ethereumnodes.com/).

Create alias that runs the command `sto` from the command-line using Docker container. If Docker image is not on your local computer yet, it will be automatically downloaded on the first `sto` run.

```sh
alias sto='docker run -p 8545:8545 -v `pwd`:`pwd` -w `pwd` miohtama/sto:latest'
```

Create INI file with your API key.

sto.ini:

```
network = ethereum

# Get API URL for your Ethereum node e.g. from your Infura dashboard
ethereum-node-url = https://mainnet.infura.io/v3/xxxxxxx
```

Build a snapshot of balances in the local SQLite database. This database also contains historical balances and can be resynced with the network. You can query any point of time.

```sh
sto --config=mainnet.ini token-scan \
  --token-address=0x9b6443b0fb9c241a7fdac375595cea13e6b7807a
```

Print out balances sorted by the top holder first:

```sh
sto --config=mainnet.init cap-table \
    --token-address=0x9b6443b0fb9c241a7fdac375595cea13e6b7807a \
    --order-by=balance \
    --order-direction=desc \
    --max-entries=99999
```

If you need a CSV, you can pipe the output of the last command to a file.

You can also query the number of token holders:

```sh
sto --config=mainnet.init cap-table \
    --token-address=0x9b6443b0fb9c241a7fdac375595cea13e6b7807a \
    --order-by=balance \
    --order-direction=desc \ 
    --max-entries=99999 \
    | wc -l
```

Comment: Great answer above (I would comment directly on it, but I cannot due to my lack of reputation). One question: is there a way to use this system with a POA side-chain such as Polygon? I just gave it a go and got the following error: web3.exceptions.ValidationError: The field extraData is 97 bytes, but should be 32. It is quite likely that you are connected to a POA chain. Thanks, and thanks for the awesome image!

Comment: Please open a separate question for this, so web3.py authors can reply.